# Insering items from RSS feed every interval

Tags: k2

I would like to insert items from RSS feed to k2, 
It has to happen every interval and I would like to only insert items that include at least one word from a given keyword list.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it can be done. Beyond the technical difficulties to solve every step, there are several extensions working in this way. Check **Joomla! extensions directory**, searching for "k2 grabber" http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=k2+grabber

- Firstly, you have to check the feed in a periodic way, getting processing time with CLI script or in a page event
- Secondly, if there are new articles, and they are not imported, you have a candidate to be imported
- Thirdly, apply all necessary filters for article cleansing
- Finally, insert the K2 article following its model

Comment: Anibal is on the mark there Priya.

For Joomla Australia's website we specifically use https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/joomgrabber/ to pull in feeds then convert them to articles. It has a K2 connector so you can map the RSS feed pull to K2 Items.